# How to define target in multilayer perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I want to do a word sense disambiguation project with multi layer perceptron in Persian language. I have some files, each for an ambiguated word. Some words have 2 senses, some 3 and some more. The files contain a lot of sentences and in front of each sentence I put a tab and then the proper sense of the ambiguated word. Then I extracted 1000 most frequent words of the file and made a binary vector (term document). (after omitting stop words and punctuation) If each word in each line is among the 1000 most frequent words, it puts 1 in the vector, unless it puts 0. So for example if a file has 500 sentence each in a line, the result is 500 lines of 1 and 0 and the columns count, is 1000 and a column for the tag of the sense. These are the input of the multi layer perceptron. Now the question is, 1) what is the target? How should I define it and what value it takes? 2) how many neurons does the output should have? 3) Is this XOR problem or And problem? (the number of hidden layers are 2, momentum is 0.02, and training iteration is 500)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are expecting? Any code written?

Comment: @ bub, I used weka. So there is no code.